# Inconsistent vendoring error about fsnotify package even though go build -mod vendor is run during the docker build stage

Tags: docker, go, go-modules

Here is the console output of Jenkins build and related error with `Docker` and `fsnotify`.

```
09:39:52  Step 1/21 : FROM golang:1.16.15-stretch as builder
09:39:52   ---> c6f80a9088b5
09:39:52  Step 2/21 : ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
09:39:52   ---> Using cache
09:39:52   ---> a7b2e4257aaa
09:39:52  Step 3/21 : WORKDIR /app
09:39:52   ---> Using cache
09:39:52   ---> 37a04577037a
09:39:52  Step 4/21 : COPY . ./
09:39:57   ---> 9f15dcf0b7cb
09:39:57  Step 5/21 : RUN go build -mod vendor       -ldflags "-w -X main.buildTime=$(date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S)         -X main.commitHash=$(git log --pretty=format:%H -n 1)         -X main.gitStatus=${GIT_STATUS}         -X main.version=${VERSION}"       ./cmd/igmpca &&     go build -mod vendor       -ldflags "-w -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.BuildTime=$(date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S)         -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.CommitHash=$(git log --pretty=format:%H -n 1)         -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.GitStatus=${GIT_STATUS}         -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.Version=${VERSION}"       ./cmd/igmpcactl
09:39:57   ---> Running in c45fc7225835
09:39:58  [91mgo: inconsistent vendoring in /app:
09:39:58    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify@v1.6.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
09:39:58  
09:39:58    To ignore the vendor directory, use -mod=readonly or -mod=mod.
09:39:58    To sync the vendor directory, run:
09:39:58        go mod vendor
09:39:58  [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c go build -mod vendor       -ldflags "-w -X main.buildTime=$(date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S)         -X main.commitHash=$(git log --pretty=format:%H -n 1)         -X main.gitStatus=${GIT_STATUS}         -X main.version=${VERSION}"       ./cmd/igmpca &&     go build -mod vendor       -ldflags "-w -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.BuildTime=$(date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S)         -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.CommitHash=$(git log --pretty=format:%H -n 1)         -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.GitStatus=${GIT_STATUS}         -X igmpca/internal/igmpcactl/config.Version=${VERSION}"       ./cmd/igmpcactl' returned a non-zero code: 1
09:39:58  make: *** [Makefile:96: docker-build] Error 1
```

`go.mod` file is as follows:

```
require (
   github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.6.0
)
```

As much as I understood, go build -mod vendor does something related to vendoring which it installs it. Why it is giving me an error that `vendor/modules.txt` and `go.mod` is not run. It basically installs vendor files according to `go.mod`. What might be the possible problem here?

I also have tried building again after I committing my `vendor/fsnotify` file and got the same error.